# addthis, isotope and nicescroll all in 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope, addthis

I have a wordpress template which include a group of share buttons from addthis

```
       <ul class="addthis extra">
            <li class="addthis-hold">
                <div class="addthis_toolbox" addthis:url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <a class="addthis_button_compact" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo GOODLAYERS_PATH; ?>/images/compact.png" width="102px" height="23" alt="email" /></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo GOODLAYERS_PATH; ?>/images/twitter-addthis.png" width="42" height="23" alt="twitter" /></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo GOODLAYERS_PATH; ?>/images/facebook-addthis.png" width="42" height="23" alt="facebook" /></a>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-51238bfa52ea314a"></script>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Secondly i have a isotope/masonry plugin bound on my elements which each have a addthis element on it.. see picture below:

[image]

So when i hover the addthis_button_compact it fails the positioning it does change if i hover on a object below this one but it only change the top: X; position..

Comment: i got the position of the mouse on hover and then set the position - didn't find any good solution :S

Comment: I went with the modal solution for stability. See answer below. I've added extras to the isotope and nothing ~felt stable~

Answer (score 2):

After attempting to redraw the toolbox, domready settings, among other things... the only reliable solution was to change to an expanded button. I was able to change the position "onmouseover" but it just didn't feel right.

Changing this:

```
<a class="addthis_button_compact"><span>Share</span></a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="addthis_button_expanded"><span>Share</span></a>
```

Shows the modal version instead, which although wasn't my initial goal, turns out quite nice. So although probably not a fix to the question, it is an alternative.